# Processing in Android Studio: can't load and saveStrings properly

Tags: android, processing

So i recently transfered my Processing-made game into Android Studio. So far i encountered a problem with savingStrings and loading them from a txt file that is located in my assets folder. The problem is if i write manually to that txt file the value i need to be stored and then try to load it it gives me an error.. Similar with savingStrings, when i save the value and run the sketch, it doesn't even show the saved value in the file i specified...
I tried everything i could find about this topic but there's not much.
I also tried adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
to the Manifest but it did't work.
In the PDE it works perfectly fine but here i cant figure out what shall i do to get it work.

This is the class:

```
class HScore{
float x;
float y;
float speed;
int points;
boolean savePoints = true;
String[] savedH = {"0"};
String[] loadedH;
HScore(){
  x = -width/5;
  y = height/14;
  speed = 0.04F;
  loadedH = loadStrings(dataPath("hscore.txt"));
  points = parseInt(loadedH[0]);

}
public void display(){
   textFont(startFont);
   fill(355);
   textSize(width/7);
   text(points,x,y);
}
public void move(){
  x = lerp(x,width/9,speed*2);
}
public void moveBack(){
  x = lerp(x,-width/5,speed*3);
}
public void update(){

  if (savePoints){
    if (score.points > points) {
      points = score.points;
    }
    savedH[0] = str(points);
    saveStrings(dataPath("hscore.txt"),savedH);
    savePoints = false;
  }
}
}
```

and this is the error that i'm getting:

```
11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 18857 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: processing.test.game_pre_release_, PID: 7590 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/data/processing.test.game_pre_release_/files/data/hscore.txt contains a path separator 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2865) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:1332) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:190) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at processing.core.PApplet.createInputRaw(Unknown Source) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at processing.core.PApplet.createInput(Unknown Source) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at processing.core.PApplet.loadStrings(Unknown Source) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at processing.test.game_pre_release_.game_pre_release_$HScore.(game_pre_release_.java:712) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at processing.test.game_pre_release_.game_pre_release_.setup(game_pre_release_.java:129) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at processing.opengl.PGLES$AndroidRenderer.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531) 11-04 15:29:05.568 7590-7630/? E/AndroidRuntime: at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Post the full stack trace. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: dataPath("hscore.txt"); gives me this: /data/data/processing.test.game_pre_release_/files/data/hscore.txt

Comment: create the folder in which you save your file, as it apparently does not exist.

Comment: Just created the folders and put them in the project folder like so : Try1/data/data/processing.test.game_pre_release_/files/data/hscore.txt , also tried putting them in the folder where my assets are, still nothing. Should i place these files another place ? Can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `SharedPreferences` and copy paste your .txt into different android string value.

Here is a quick example of how it work :

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "yourString");
editor.commit();
```

Then to get it back :

```
String yourString = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "defaultValue");
```